# Cant find migrations table when trying to migrate table in laravel

Tags: laravel, migration

Im new to laravel and im trying to run `php artisan migrate` but  im getting this error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access  violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that cor responds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-DYNAM IC' at line 1 (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_i ncrement primary key, `migration` varchar(191) not null, `batch` int not null) d efault character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci engine = InnoDB ROW_FORM AT-DYNAMIC)
```

also mentioning that my database is empty and have no tables, and i had tried to run `php artisan migrate:rollback` or `reset` but the console is telling me that no migrations where found

Comment: share your migration table code

Comment: I think the problem is that I deleted the migrations table and Users table from my database, how can i retrieve them back?

Comment: restore from backup?

Comment: No, I mean recreate both tables in the database.

Comment: well you'd have to get hold of the script which created the tables in the first place. It'll be there somewhere in the source code. Or just drop and re-create the database. But if you have a recent backup (which you should, even for testing databases), then it might be easier to restore from that. Then you won't lose so much data.

Answer (score 0):

run php artisan migrate:install it will solve the problem